# Scatter plot coloring of data under the region of a function in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to plot bunch of points and also on the same graph plot a function cosx. The idea is to see the points that fall under the curve.

I have graph of cosx:

```
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi) #x range between 0 and pi
y = np.cos(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Now I need to plot `x = [2, 0.9, 2.6, 3.1]` and `y = [0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2]` 
I can plot them as scatter plot but how would I combine both and preferably color code the points that fall under the curve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can seperate the scatter points into two lists, one for points under the line and one for points over the line. Then you can plot both lists.

Your data would be inserted instead of the random numbers in points_x and points_y

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi) #x range between 0 and pi
y = np.cos(x)

N = 100
points_x = np.random.rand(N)*np.pi
points_y = np.random.rand(N)*2.-1.

points_over = [(xi,yi) for xi,yi in zip(points_x,points_y) if np.cos(xi) < yi]
points_under = [(xi,yi) for xi,yi in zip(points_x,points_y) if np.cos(xi) >= yi]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.scatter(*zip(*points_over),c='g')
plt.scatter(*zip(*points_under),c='r')
plt.show()
```

Producing something like:

[image]